# Is every real function $L_1$-approximable by a step function?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, approximation, step-function

## Preliminaries

As usual, a *step function* $\eta$ is a function that has only finitely many values and is of the form:
\begin{equation}
\eta(x) = \begin{cases}
\eta_1,\quad x\in[a=t_0, t_1]\\
\eta_2,\quad x\in(t_1, t_2]\\
...\\
\eta_n,\quad x\in(t_{n-1}, b = t_n]
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
We say that a function $f$ is $L_1$-approximable on $\Omega$ by a step functions $\eta$ iff
\begin{equation}
\forall \epsilon>0,\quad \exists \eta_\epsilon\in \{\eta_n\}: \int_\Omega |f(x) - \eta_n(x)|dx < \epsilon,
\end{equation}
where $\{\eta_n\}$ is the set of all step functions.

## Question

Is every real function $L_1$-approximable by a step functions? If not, what conditions must be satisfied for those functions which **is** approximable in the latter sense?

## Modification

Maybe it is interesting to modify definition of a step function and allow it to assume *infinitely but countably* many values.

Comment: Yes, ever $L^1$ function can be approximated in this way. For giving you a proof, it would be good to know what you already know about integrable functions. Do you know that they can be approximated by continuous functions with compact support?